# CSS :Select all elements descendent of X but not descendents of Y

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to be able to select all elements of class zz that are descendants of an element of class xx but not a descendant of class yy.

Consider the following:

```
<div class="xx">
  ... arbitrary depth ...
    <div class="zz" id="1">
    </div>

    <div class="yy">
       <div class=zz" id="2">
       </div>
    ...
    </div>
...
</div>
```

The selector I'm looking for would in the above case return the id1 element but not id2 element.

Comment: my idea, not possible!

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible as this is essentially a [**parent selector**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

Hopefully it is less complicated to combine a few `:not()` than to do a bunch of set/reset rules.

```css
:not(.yy):not(body) > .zz { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="xx">
  ... arbitrary depth ...
    <div>
      <div class="zz" id="1a">1a
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="zz" id="1b">1b
    </div>

    <div class="yy">
       <div class="zz" id="2">2
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="zz" id="3">3
</div>
```

The second best, and if I were you, would be to add an extra `div` for your arbitrary elements, to match the `.yy` class in depth.

If that is possible, then the `.xx :not(.yy) .zz { ... }` rule that [fcalderan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35440435/2827823) suggests will work

```css
.xx :not(.yy) .zz { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="xx">
  <div>
    
      ... arbitrary depth ...

    <div>
      <div class="zz" id="1a">1a
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zz" id="1b">1b
    </div>
    

  </div>
  <div class="yy">
    <div class="zz" id="2">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="zz" id="3">3
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. It will select also those zz's that are not descendants of xx. I've updated your brilliant example and added item3. Item3 *shouldn't* be selected.

Comment: @peterh You can combine `:not()` ... updated my answer

Comment: I've given you an upvote for trying. :-)   Unfortunately I do not have control over the HTML as you may have guessed. Both of your solutions carry implicit assumptions with them. These assumptions are not true in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write a selector like that which works in a general case.

However, you can use

```css
.xx .zz {
  /* Some styles */
}
.yy .xx .zz, .xx .yy .zz { /* Or maybe just `.yy .zz` */
  /* Undo previous styles */
}
```

Of course, this requires knowing the styles of `.xx .zz` elements before the first ruleset applies.

Answer (score 0):

this is for only your scenario. based on your given html structure.

```
.xx > .zz {}
```

but this is only select immediate child "zz" class of "xx" class